# CommonJS module how to create getter

Tags: commonjs, titanium-modules

i'm working with Titanium, but this question is related to CommonJS, i'm trying to create a module but I also need a getter for a variable.

I admit that I haven't all clear in my mind, it's the first time that i'm working with titanium and commonjs, maybe you could also give me something to read.

This is my code:

Picker.js

```
var cat;
function Picker(){
  this.cat = 0;
}

Picker.prototype.getCat = function() {
  return this.cat;
};

module.exports = Picker;
```

List.js

```
var Picker = require('myPath/Picker');
var picker = new Picker();

var cat = picker.getCat();
```

But if i print cat's value it is undefined, not 0... where i'm wrong?

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using the prototype?

```
function Picker(){
  this.cat = 0;
  this.getCat = function() {
      return this.cat;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you checked to see if the Picker being returned is non-null? It could be your paths are off cause both of these should work, its not a CommonJS problem.

Comment: Yea, the picker is ok: if i use a global variable to read the content of cat it's working, but i'd like to not using it!

Comment: I copied your code and it works fine for me... The problem is not commonJS, but regardless [heres link to a good guide about it.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium)